# Restrict remote desktop access

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a windows 2008/20012 server running on AWS. These servers are accessed by me(administrator) and few other users in company. I want don't want these users to go outside the company and access the server. I have already restricted user to not be able to access server after certain time based on their user id. I also want to restrict anyone to RDP into server from any other client machines than I choose. I have access to those client machines so if solution you provide will need me to install something on client machines prior to they accessing it, that should be fine.

Comment: It's bad form to cross posts the same question across multiple sites. This isn't AverageUser.com, we do notice that sort of thing. The question on SO will certainly be closed because this question is completely off topic over there.

Comment: closing that one now..wasn't aware of this policy and of this site prior to opening it StackOverflow